# How can I save files to server with filemanager?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have edit_area plugin (what ever you like to call it), It's a text editor what I want to use to save files into server, it has js save, open functions.

```
function save(id, content){


    }


function load(id){

        }
```

*http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/*

**Is there a plugin for saving texteditor files to server with these functions, like a php file manager API that can implement these save,open functions?**

Answer (score 0):

You could not upload any files like images, because its a source code.
Take a look at the docs http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/editarea/docs/configuration.html. There you could personalize your toolbar, like

```
toolbar: "new_document, save, load, |, charmap, |, search, go_to_line, |, undo, redo, |, select_font, |, change_smooth_selection, highlight, reset_highlight, |, help"
```

With the command "save" you get your save-button. At this button you could bind an function:

```
editAreaLoader.init({
 ...
 toolbar: "xx",
 save_callback: "my_save_function"
});



function my_save_function ( id , content ) {

 $.ajax({type:"POST",url:window.location.href,data:{'code':content}}).always(function(return){

  alert(return);//response from your server

 });

}
```

For the `$.ajax` command use the jQuery library. https://jquery.com/.
Than you could save it with PHP (from $_POST['code']) in a file (http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-put-contents.php) or database.